# Do not see data written from Spark in ADX

Tags: apache-spark, azure-data-explorer

I am using azure-kusto-spark to write data to ADX, I can see schema created in ADX, but I do not see any data, there is not any error from log, note I try it using local spark.

```
df.show();
df.write()
        .format("com.microsoft.kusto.spark.datasource")
        .option(KustoSinkOptions.KUSTO_CLUSTER(), cluster)
        .option(KustoSinkOptions.KUSTO_DATABASE(), db)
        .option(KustoSinkOptions.KUSTO_TABLE(), table)
        .option(KustoSinkOptions.KUSTO_AAD_APP_ID(), client_id)
        .option(KustoSinkOptions.KUSTO_AAD_APP_SECRET(), client_key)
        .option(KustoSinkOptions.KUSTO_AAD_AUTHORITY_ID(), "microsoft.com")
        .option(KustoSinkOptions.KUSTO_TABLE_CREATE_OPTIONS(), "CreateIfNotExist")
        .mode(SaveMode.Append)
        .save();
```

```
22/12/13 12:06:14 INFO QueuedIngestClient: Creating a new IngestClient
22/12/13 12:06:14 INFO ResourceManager: Refreshing Ingestion Auth Token
22/12/13 12:06:16 INFO ResourceManager: Refreshing Ingestion Resources
22/12/13 12:06:16 INFO KustoConnector: ContainerProvider: Got 2 storage SAS with command :'.create tempstorage'. from service 'ingest-engineermetricdata.eastus'
22/12/13 12:06:16 INFO KustoConnector: ContainerProvider: Got 2 storage SAS with command :'.create tempstorage'. from service 'ingest-engineermetricdata.eastus'
22/12/13 12:06:16 INFO KustoConnector: KustoWriter$: finished serializing rows in partition 0 for requestId: '9065b634-3b74-4993-830b-16ee534409d5' 
22/12/13 12:06:16 INFO KustoConnector: KustoWriter$: finished serializing rows in partition 1 for requestId: '9065b634-3b74-4993-830b-16ee534409d5' 
22/12/13 12:06:17 INFO KustoConnector: KustoWriter$: Ingesting from blob - partition: 0 requestId: '9065b634-3b74-4993-830b-16ee534409d5' 
22/12/13 12:06:17 INFO KustoConnector: KustoWriter$: Ingesting from blob - partition: 1 requestId: '9065b634-3b74-4993-830b-16ee534409d5' 
22/12/13 12:06:19 INFO Executor: Finished task 1.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 1). 2135 bytes result sent to driver
22/12/13 12:06:19 INFO Executor: Finished task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0). 2135 bytes result sent to driver
22/12/13 12:06:19 INFO TaskSetManager: Finished task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0) in 6306 ms on 192.168.50.160 (executor driver) (1/2)
22/12/13 12:06:19 INFO TaskSetManager: Finished task 1.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 1) in 6231 ms on 192.168.50.160 (executor driver) (2/2)
22/12/13 12:06:19 INFO TaskSchedulerImpl: Removed TaskSet 0.0, whose tasks have all completed, from pool 
22/12/13 12:06:19 INFO DAGScheduler: ResultStage 0 (foreachPartition at KustoWriter.scala:107) finished in 7.070 s
22/12/13 12:06:19 INFO DAGScheduler: Job 0 is finished. Cancelling potential speculative or zombie tasks for this job
22/12/13 12:06:19 INFO TaskSchedulerImpl: Killing all running tasks in stage 0: Stage finished
22/12/13 12:06:19 INFO DAGScheduler: Job 0 finished: foreachPartition at KustoWriter.scala:107, took 7.157414 s
22/12/13 12:06:19 INFO KustoConnector: KustoClient: Polling on ingestion results for requestId: 9065b634-3b74-4993-830b-16ee534409d5, will move data to destination table when finished
22/12/13 12:13:30 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Removed broadcast_0_piece0 on 192.168.50.160:56364 in memory (size: 4.9 KiB, free: 2004.6 MiB)
```

Local Spark writes data to ADX

Comment: Your syntax is wrong. You should remove the brackets that follows `write` as well as all the brackets that follows the *KustoSinkOptions* parameters.

Answer (score 0):

The following code works.

Tested on Azure Databricks.
11.3 LTS (includes Apache Spark 3.3.0, Scala 2.12).
com.microsoft.azure.kusto:kusto-spark_3.0_2.12:3.1.6

```
import com.microsoft.kusto.spark.datasink.KustoSinkOptions
import org.apache.spark.sql.{SaveMode, SparkSession}

val cluster = "..."
val client_id = "..."
val client_key = "..."
val authority = "..."
val db = "mydb"
val table = "mytable"

val df = spark.range(10)
df.show()
df.write
    .format("com.microsoft.kusto.spark.datasource")
    .option(KustoSinkOptions.KUSTO_CLUSTER, cluster)
    .option(KustoSinkOptions.KUSTO_DATABASE, db)
    .option(KustoSinkOptions.KUSTO_TABLE, table)
    .option(KustoSinkOptions.KUSTO_AAD_APP_ID, client_id)
    .option(KustoSinkOptions.KUSTO_AAD_APP_SECRET, client_key)
    .option(KustoSinkOptions.KUSTO_AAD_AUTHORITY_ID, authority)
    .option(KustoSinkOptions.KUSTO_TABLE_CREATE_OPTIONS, "CreateIfNotExist")
    .mode(SaveMode.Append)
    .save()
```

---

The ingestion time depends on the [ingestion batching policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/management/batchingpolicy) of the table.

**Defaults and limits**

| Type | Property | Default | Low latency setting | Minimum value | Maximum value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Number of items | MaximumNumberOfItems | 1000 | 1000 | 1 | 25,000 |
| Data size (MB) | MaximumRawDataSizeMB | 1024 | 1024 | 100 | 4096 |
| Time (sec) | MaximumBatchingTimeSpan | 300 | 20 - 30 | 10 | 1800 |

Comment: just an update, I saw the data finally, it just had a very long delay for the batch insert

Comment: As I wrote,  you can control this time by setting the ingestion batching policy